# How can i make tabs in pygtk closable?

Tags: python, tabs, gtk, pygtk

i am using python with gtk, trying to make a simple text editor with tabs, i am still new, so i wonder how can i make the tabs closable and reordable ? it is much easier in qt, but i loved gtk more. this is my code:

```
import gtk
from tab import *

 class Dash(gtk.Notebook):
    def __init__(self):
        super(gtk.Notebook,self).__init__()
        self.defaultTab()

    def defaultTab(self):
        tab = Tab()
        self.append_page(tab.child,tab.label)
```

the other module "tab" has some variables :

```
from launchers import *

class Tab():
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = gtk.Label("New Tab")
        self.type = "dash"
        launchers = Launchers()
        self.child = launchers
```

so what i gotta do ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using a `gtk.Label` when appending a new page to the `gtk.Notebook`, you need to create a `gtk.HBox` that contains both a `gtk.Label` and a `gtk.Button`. More or less, something like this:

```
class Dash(gtk.Notebook):
...
    def defaultTab(self):
        self.append_page(tab.child,tab.header)
...
class Tab():
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        header = gtk.HBox()
        title_label = gtk.Label()
        image = gtk.Image()
        image.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_CLOSE, gtk.ICON_SIZE_MENU)
        close_button = gtk.Button()
        close_button.set_image(image)
        close_button.set_relief(gtk.RELIEF_NONE)
        self.connect(close_button, 'clicked', self.close_cb)

        header.pack_start(title_label,
                          expand=True, fill=True, padding=0)
        header.pack_end(close_button,
                        expand=False, fill=False, padding=0)
        header.show_all()
        self.header = header
        ...
```

This is just to display the close button. To actually close the tab, you'll need to handle the `clicked` signal from the button.

Answer (score 5):

To make the tab reorderable, do this after your `append_page()` call:

```
self.child_set_property(tab.child, 'reorderable', True)
```

or:

```
self.set_tab_reorderable(tab.child, True)
```

Here's a short example:

```
import gtk

win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
notebook = gtk.Notebook()
page1 = gtk.Label('This is the first page')
page2 = gtk.Label('This is the second page')

notebook.append_page(page1, gtk.Label('P1'))
notebook.append_page(page2, gtk.Label('P2'))
notebook.props.border_width = 12
notebook.set_tab_reorderable(page1, True)
notebook.set_tab_reorderable(page2, True)
win.add(notebook)

win.connect('delete-event', gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: Did you make sure that `tab.child` was added to the notebook container first?

Comment: i tried self.set_tab_reorderable(tab,true) it working without throwing errors, but when i ran the program, i couldn't reorder the tabs, and yeah i put the code after append_page()

Comment: Works for me. See the example I added.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example to show how to create a notebook with tabs and an on_close handler:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk

class Tab():
    def __init__(self, title, parent):
        self.title = title
        self.parent = parent
        self.header = gtk.HBox()
        self.title = gtk.Label(label=title)
        image = gtk.Image()
        image.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_CLOSE, gtk.IconSize.MENU)
        close_button = gtk.Button()
        close_button.set_image(image)
        close_button.set_relief(gtk.ReliefStyle.NONE)
        close_button.connect("clicked", self.on_tab_close)

        self.header.pack_start(self.title,
                          expand=True, fill=True, padding=0)
        self.header.pack_end(close_button,
                        expand=False, fill=False, padding=0)
        self.header.show_all()

    def on_tab_close(self, button):
        self.parent.remove_page(self.parent.get_current_page())

class Dash(gtk.Notebook):

    def new_tab(self, title):
        tab = Tab(title, self)
        self.sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.page = self.sw
        self.page.add(gtk.Label(label=title))
        self.append_page(self.page, tab.header)


d = Dash()
d.new_tab("first")
d.new_tab("second")
d.new_tab("third")
window = gtk.Window(gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
window.set_default_size(400, 400);
window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
window.add(d)
window.show_all()

gtk.main()
```

[image: output]