# Is it possible to use other widget in the tab lable other than Gtk.Label?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, pygtk, pygobject

In python gtk [docs](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Notebook.html) for notebook widget, there is a mention of `append_page` which adds a page/tab to the notebook.

The second parameter in `append_page` is a widget which goes in the title of the page (inplace of the default **Page 1**), but when any other widget is provided it does not show anything.

Is it possible to add a a custom widget that has two child widgets like (`Gtk.Label`, `Gtk.Button`) to close specific tabs from the notebook when needed.

A custom widget implementation would be

```
class PageTitle(Gtk.Box):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = Gtk.Label("title")
        self.close = Gtk.Button("close")
```

Again the goal is to have two widgets in the page title.

I tried passing an object of the class `PageTitle` but was not successful as this resulted in an empty page title

Comment: It is certainly possible in gtk3.  I don't know python, but in the documentation, it seems that the object you pass in must be a `Gtk.Widget`.  Is `PageTitle` a `Gtk.Widget`?

Comment: `PageTitle` is a `Gtk.widget` since `Gtk.Box` inherits from `Gtk.Widget`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not add the childern widgets to the custom widget `PageTitle` and you should call `self.show_all()` in `__init__` in `PageTitle` class to show the label and button, here is another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850043/how-can-i-make-tabs-in-pygtk-closable)

The code you want to use looks something like this

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class PageTitle(Gtk.Box):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = Gtk.Label("title")
        self.close = Gtk.Button("close")
        self.add(self.title)
        self.add(self.close)
        self.show_all()

class GUI(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.set_default_size(400, 500)
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.notebook = Gtk.Notebook()
        self.add(self.notebook)
        self.textview = Gtk.TextView()
        self.notebook.append_page(self.textview, PageTitle())
        self.show_all()

app = GUI()
Gtk.main()
```